# C# - How can I set my Datagrid enabled = false and still have a scrollbar without using readonly()?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, compact-framework

I was requested to make an app that read barcodes and update a datatable on the screen that would update the database after the data gathering.

The problem is that there's a column that must be updated at execution time every time a barcode would be read, but the user shouldn't be able to edit the cell by writing on the device keyboard.

So I tried to set my columns to readonly, but when I do this, it's not possible to update the value on the datatable, then I tried to set the DataGrid enabled = false, but then the scrollbar stopped working, and I need it because it's a small device and there are other columns that the user should be able to see.

Is there a simple way to solve this ? I'm using .net compact 3.5

This is my code for button that loads the DataGrid:

```
DataTable tabela    = new DataTable();
DataTable codbarras = new DataTable();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ultimopedido = textBox1.Text;
    try
    {
        FbDataReader leitor;
        FbDataReader leitorbarras;
        string query1 = "SELECT CAST(0 AS DOUBLE PRECISION)SEPARADO, CAST(ITEMORCAMENTO.SALDOITEMORCA - ITEMORCAMENTO.QUANTITEMSEPARADO AS DOUBLE PRECISION)SALDO, ITEMORCAMENTO.QUANTITEMSEPARADO, ITEMORCAMENTO.SALDOITEMORCA, PRODUTO.PRODUTOID, PRODUTO.REFPROD, PRODUTO.NOMEPROD, PRODUTO.ESTOQUEPED, ITEMORCAMENTO.QUANTITEMORCA, ITEMORCAMENTO.ITEMORCAMENTOID, ORCAMENTO.STATUSORCA";
        query1 += " FROM ORCAMENTO ";
        query1 += " LEFT JOIN ITEMORCAMENTO ";
        query1 += " ON ORCAMENTO.ORCAMENTOID = ITEMORCAMENTO.ORCAMENTOID ";
        query1 += " INNER JOIN PRODUTO ";
        query1 += " ON ITEMORCAMENTO.PRODUTOID = PRODUTO.PRODUTOID ";
        query1 += " WHERE ORCAMENTO.ORCAMENTOID = " + textBox1.Text + " AND ";
        query1 += " ORCAMENTO.STATUSORCA = 4 AND ";
        query1 += " ORCAMENTO.SEPARADO = 0 AND ";
        query1 += " ITEMORCAMENTO.STATUSITEMORCA IN (0,1) ";
        query1 += " ORDER BY PRODUTO.PRODUTOID";
        string queryUp = "UPDATE ORCAMENTO SET SEPARADO = 1 WHERE ORCAMENTOID =" + textBox1.Text;


        leitor = conexao.Executar(Conexao.FbConexao, query1);
        tabela.Load(leitor);
        if (tabela.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            conexao.Atualizar(Conexao.FbConexao, queryUp);
            dataGrid1.DataSource = tabela;
            DataGridTableStyle ts               = new DataGridTableStyle();
            DataGridColumnStyle celId           = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridColumnStyle celQuantitem    = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridColumnStyle celSaldo        = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridColumnStyle celRef          = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            ts.MappingName = tabela.TableName;
            celId.MappingName           = "PRODUTOID";
            celId.HeaderText            = "Id";
            celQuantitem.MappingName    = "SEPARADO";
            celQuantitem.HeaderText     = "Separado";
            celSaldo.MappingName        = "SALDO";
            celSaldo.HeaderText         = "Saldo";
            celRef.MappingName          = "REFPROD";
            celRef.HeaderText           = "Referência";
            celId.Width = 50;
            celQuantitem.Width = 75;
            celSaldo.Width = 50;
            celRef.Width = 75;
            ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(celId);
            ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(celQuantitem);
            ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(celSaldo);
            ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(celRef);
            dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(ts);

            tabela.Columns["SEPARADO"].ReadOnly = true;

            textBox1.Enabled    = false;
            button1.Enabled     = false;
            textBox2.Enabled    = true;
            button6.Enabled     = true;
            button2.Enabled     = true;
            button3.Enabled     = true;
            button4.Enabled     = true;
            button5.Enabled     = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não foram encontrados dados disponíveis");
        }

        string query2 = "SELECT B.CODBARRAS, B.PRODUTOID, B.ITEMORCAMENTOID" +
                        " FROM ITEMORCAMENTO A" +
                        " INNER JOIN CODBARRASPRODUTO B" +
                        " ON A.PRODUTOID = B.PRODUTOID" +
                        " WHERE B.ITEMORCAMENTOID = 0 AND" +
                        " A.ORCAMENTOID = " + textBox1.Text + "AND " +
                        " B.ITEMORCAMENTOID = 0";
        leitorbarras = conexao.Executar(Conexao.FbConexao, query2);
        codbarras.Load(leitorbarras);
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: please use @ in front every string, in this case you can not use + (concatenate) on every line. Also use sql command parameters to avoid sql injection and improve your app performance !

Comment: the problem if I understand it correctly is that the barcode entry field, you want users to only be able to populate it with a scan entry, not a keypress? You should be able to override the onKeyPress(and others) to not accept the key entry. Since the scan wont use those actions then it should still work.  Im not sure on this one so just check and let me know

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx has an example of how to override a text field so that numbers are only allowed, but you should be able to work with this for your specific purpose

Answer (score 0):

I think a readonly collection might work for you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx

But there is another way too, you can change the cell type to be a label or textblock.  To do that you will need to change the datagrid templates.